# str not callable TypeError with Queues and Processes

Tags: python, parallel-processing, queue, typeerror, callable

I try to run this line:

```
print '%s queued as job %r' % (job.name(), jobs_queued.qsize())
```

and I get this error pointing at that line:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

After looking around, I noted that this error was primarily caused by using 'str' as a variable, however I have done no such thing. Could anyone give their insight?

jobs_queued is a Queue(), and job is a Process()

```
jobs_queued = Queue()
job = multiprocessing.Process(name=phi_dir, target=task, args=(phi_dir,))
```

phi_dir is a string, task is a function that calls a shell script.

Comment: this error usually occurs because you try to use a type str object as if it were a function ie:

s(a) where s is a string. I don't think it has anything to do with trying to name a variable str. There must be something more to your code - this line works for me if I use ("hi",12) as the tuple. job.name() looks suspicious.

Comment: as dustin pointed out below :) sorry my edit box was open too long.

Comment: As a side note, have you taken a look at `multiprocessing.Pool`?  That may take care of much of what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd have to look, but I'm on a tablet. Chances are that job.name is a string, instead of an instance method. Try removing the parenthesis from job.name().